# Equal margin space for flex items that wrap in flexbox grid

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I am trying to create a responsive grid with flexbox:

- On large screens, there should be three columns in one row
- On smaller screens, just two rows or one

My code so far:

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.gridColumn {
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="gridColumn">
    <p>first column</p>
  </div>
  <div class="gridColumn">
    <p>second column</p>
  </div>
  <div class="gridColumn">
    <p>third column</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I would like to set margins only **between** the columns (not on the sides of the grid as well), which should also behave correctly when the screen is resized. Does anybody know of a way to achieve this?

Comment: Barring media queries, maybe something like this will work for you: https://jsfiddle.net/usLowo22/2/

Comment: @Michael_B unfortunately this doesn't work – there should only be a margin between the columns, not also on the left and right of the grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a margin to the grid items...

```
.gridColumn {
    margin: $margin;
}
```

... which is then offset by its container.

```
.grid {
    margin: -$margin;
}
```

To avoid overflow, you could apply `overflow-x: hidden` to the `body`.

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kXOJLz)

Answer (score 0):

It's crashed on this part of code

> .gridColumn + .gridColumn {
>     margin-left: 20px;
>   }

You should to try use media query and set margin-left: 0; on small screens.

Above part of code is still working because flex-wrap only changing the position of the "third column", that column still have "sister" before and margin-left is working.